# Alert no deja de aparecer

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        formLaboralLoad();
        formLugarLaborado(null);
        formSaludLoad();
        segundaValidacion(); 
    });
    function segundaValidacion(){
        $('#erp_planillasbundle_solicitudemptype_dpi').blur(function(){
            if($(this).val().length != 13){
                alert("El dpi debe tener 13 caracteres");
                $('#guardar').hide();
              }else{
                validar_dpi();
            } 
        });
        $('#erp_planillasbundle_solicitudemptype_validDpi').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });    
        $('#erp_planillasbundle_solicitudemptype_validDpi').blur(function(){
            if ($(this).val() != $('#erp_planillasbundle_solicitudemptype_dpi').val()) {
                alert("El dpi no Coincide");
                $('#saveAll-btn').prop('disabled', true);
                $("#errorAlGuardar").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign' aria-hidden='true'></span> El dpi no Coincide");
                $("#errorAlGuardar").show()              
            }else{
                $('#saveAll-btn').prop('disabled', false);
                $("#errorAlGuardar").hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

tengo la siguiente funcion y el problema es que a la hora de presionar tab en el primer input aparece la validacion que los campos no son igual pero no deja de aparecer una y otra vez el alert

Comment: Me imagino que cuando te posicionas sobre el control que lanza el alert cuando no se cumple tu validación muestra el error, pero al salir del alert el navegador vuelve a entrar en el control sin tu intervenir, por consiguiente se veulve a lanzar el evento blur y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Agrega tambien tu HTML

Comment: Si lo que te comente arriba sucede intenta cambiar el evento donde lanzas el error por keypress o keydown o incluso, mouse_enter, click, etc

Comment: muchas Gracias!